# Azure Function - Azure Active Directory App - Expose an API - Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with Easy Auth enabled. I want to expose an API via the related registered app in the Azure Active Directory. Up to know I was able to use the Azure Function App URI for that:

[image]

But when I try to that now, I get the following error:

> Error detail: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified
> domain of the organization or its subdomain

Why? And how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a change with 15.10.2021 in the Azure Web API authentication. The URI used as identifier needs to be part of the verified domain list in the customer tenant or the value uses the default scheme (api://{appId}) provided by AAD.

See also https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-new-restrictions-to-azurewebsitesnet-domain

To make it work with the default api:// value and Easy Auth you need to add this values to "Allowed Token Audiences":

[image]